# How to deduce that $K_{m,n}$ is hamiltonian iff $m = n\ge 2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

I know how to prove that a bipartite graph $G$ with bipartitions $B$ and $W$ must both have the same number of vertices. I am having trouble, though, proving that they must have at least 2 vertices. Any help?

Comment: If $B$ and $W$ only have 1 vertex each, then we are talking about $K_{1,1}$, which is just a single edge joining two vertices. But it's clear that that graph has no cycle, Hamiltonian or otherwise, isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You have two cases: $m \geq n$ or $m = 1, n = 1$. Gerry Myerson covered $K_{1, 1}$ pretty well. Now if $m \geq 1$, pick a vertex $v_{1}$ from the first partition. We consider $n = 2, m = 1$ to demonstrate the concept. It is connected to the only vertex in the second partition. We then pick a different vertex in the first partition. Since no vertices in the first partition are adjacent, and since there is only one vertex in the second partition, it is impossible to return to our starting vertex without re-using the vertex in partition two. This contradicts the definition of a Hamiltonian circuit.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do not understand why those are the two cases you proposed for consideration, though. In particular, m >= 2, n = 1 doesn't seem to fit the restriction m = n. Where is my misunderstanding? :)

Comment: It's a proof by contrapositive. Suppose $K_{m, n}$ is not Hamiltonian. Then you get either $m = n = 1$ or $m \neq n$ (and WLOG, we assume $m > n$). So you'll actually want to generalize my argument some, but it should still give you an idea of what is going on.

Comment: Oh, I see! Your proof makes a lot of sense, then. Thank you!